# Angular OpenID: Redirect to login before app loads in browser

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, angular-oauth2-oidc

I am using Angular 12 with [angular-oauth2-oidc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-oauth2-oidc) and so far I've successfully set up authentication. However, right before being redirected to the login the application is being loaded (only for a splitsecond, but still). Is there any way to hide the app completely unless you're logged in?

Comment: You can take a look at `APP_INITIALIZER`. If you return an observable from it, it will wait for it to complete before continuing with the initialization of the app. https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu I tried that approach, however I still had the same issue as described, not entirely sure why. Trying to load auth with `DoBootstrap` before bootstrapping `AppComponent` produced the same issue. I eventually solved it by combining `APP_INITIALIZER` with an AuthGuard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using routing then you could look into using [guards](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) to prevent any of the routes from being loaded if the user is not authorized.
A guard would look something like

```
class AuthenticatedGuard implements CanActivate {
  userLoggedIn = AuthService.isLoggedIn;
  canActivate() {
    if (this.userLoggedIn) {
     return true;
    } else {
     return false;
    }
  }
}
```

And then to prevent the app from loading routes that require authorization, in the routing module you could add the guard individually with the `canActivate` property or even have them as children of a route to save yourself some time like below:

```
{    
  path: '',
  component: AppComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthenticatedGuard],
  children: [
     { path: '', component: HomeComponent }, // Other routes here
  ]
}
```